# Buttons in LinearLayout issue

Tags: android, button, dialog, android-linearlayout

I have a custom dialog which has 3 buttons and sometimes it has one button only. When I have 3 buttons, the `LinearLayout` fits those buttons well in itself. But when I have just one button, it gives the whole width available to a single button making that button look too big. I want that, if there's only one button, it should only take half the the complete width available or should wrap content (Button image.) See following images for reference-

[image: 3 buttons dialog]

[image: 1 button dialog]

Comment: I think Jason is asking: Please post the XML for your layout so that we can have a look and answer meaningfully

Comment: I don't think this question deserves the downvote it got. It's a highly valid and clear question. Yes, one might want the XML when pinpointing errors but I think one could give several good answers even without the current layout implementation. Please don't be too triggerhappy with your downvotes, people!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Refer this XML file which is similar to your requirement. Just visibility to gone to not required button.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:weightSum="3" android:gravity="center_horizontal">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button"/>


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Also; if you want all buttons to have the same width you should set the `android:layout_width` attributes to "0dp" on all of them. As of the example given by @Agarwal your buttons will first get a width as they wrap their content (the "Contacts" button will get wider than the "Add" button) and then the remaining width is distributed evenly among the three buttons. If they all start with a zero-width they will all be of the exact same width after the final size re-distribution. I really thought I saw an answer explaining this, but obviously my eyes are tricking me...

Answer (score 1):

In order to have one button take up half the available screen width you need to

1. set `android:weightSum="2"` in the parent `LinearLayout`
2. set `android:layout_weight="1"` in the `Button`